# Python tuple index recursion: "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type float"

Tags: python, indexing, tuples, sequence

I'm writing a program to evaluate a polynomial, given as a tuple of coefficients (going from degree 0 to n).  I define the function, then call it with raw_inputs of the polynomial and the value of x.

This is in Python 2.5.4

This is an exercise from an online course in programming, and for the life of me I can't figure out what's going wrong; my program is identical to the given solution as well, which returns the same error:

```
"line 19, in evaluate_poly
    polySum += poly[n] * (x ** n)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"
```

The code is as follows:

```
def evaluate_poly(poly, x):
    """
    Computes the polynomial function for a given value x. Returns that value.

    Example:
    >>> poly = (0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 9.3, 7.0)    # f(x) = 7x^4 + 9.3x^3 + 5x^2
    >>> x = -13
    >>> print evaluate_poly(poly, x)  # f(-13) = 7(-13)^4 + 9.3(-13)^3 + 5(-13)^2
    180339.9

    poly: tuple of numbers, length > 0
    x: number
    returns: float
    """

    polySum = 0.0
    for n in xrange(0, len(poly)-1,1):
        polySum += poly[n] * (x ** n)
    return polySum


function = tuple(raw_input('Enter your polynomial as a tuple of numbers, going from degree 0 to n: '))
x = float(raw_input('Enter the value of x for which your polynomial is to be evaluated: '))


print 'f(x) =', evaluate_poly(function, x)
```

For the first input I'll do something like (1,1,1,1) and then I'll input 1 for the second, and I get the above error.

What's going on here?  I thought the brackets with the variable n in the for loop would just index every successive value in the tuple, but the error seems to be saying that poly[n] is a sequence instead of one number.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: try `print`ing `function` after assigning it - that'll give you the source of your error

Answer (score 2):

```
function = tuple(raw_input('Enter your polynomial as a tuple of numbers, going from degree 0 to n: '))
```

This line doesn't do what you think it does. Here's an example of what it does:

```
>>> function = tuple(raw_input('Enter your polynomial as a tuple of numbers, goi
ng from degree 0 to n: '))
Enter your polynomial as a tuple of numbers, going from degree 0 to n: (1, 1)
>>> function
('(', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ')')
```

It takes the user's input string and turns it into a tuple of individual characters. If you want the user to input a literal tuple and have it treated as such, try [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
function = ast.literal_eval(raw_input('Enter your polynomial as a tuple of numbers, going from degree 0 to n: '))
```

While we're fixing bugs, it's worth noting that your evaluation code is bugged:

```
    for n in xrange(0, len(poly)-1,1):
```

Since the sequence returned by `xrange` excludes the `stop` parameter, this stops just before the last term of the polynomial. You want

```
    for n in xrange(len(poly)):
```

or better yet, use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), or use an evaluation algorithm that doesn't require the index and the exponentiation:

```
value = 0
for i in reversed(poly):
    value = x*value + i
```

Answer (score 0):

`tuple()` does not do what you think it does. Try `ast.literal_eval()` instead.